# An interesting question from "Group Theory: A First Journey," (page 4, section 2.3).

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations, magma

I am currently studying the manuscript **Group Theory: A First Journey** by Vipul Naik. [It is available from the web page](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~vipul/mathjourneys/). In this manuscript the author proposes the following question:

> Suppose the ordering of the elements in the rows and columns is the same. Then what kind of multiplication table would a magma have if it were to be a group? More generally, what are the constraints on the multiplication table corresponding to each of the properties that we can talk of for a binary operation?

(page 4, section 2.3)

No matter from what angle I have thought about this question, I can't seem to grasp what the author wants from his readers.

Anyone?

Comment: For example (as I understand it), if you want your structure to be commutative, your table has to be symmetric, since you want $ab=ba$. If you want every element to be invertible, then you want "1"-s in certain places...

Comment: Well, the identity and the inverse have nice enough descriptions in this context. For the associativity, it is a bit more tricky, since this involves more than two elements.

Comment: See [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the existence of *unique* inverses.  What does this do to the rows and columns of the multiplication table?  For example, what if $a\star b = c$ but then $a\star d = c$ too?

You'll also need an identity element, and in particular this must be a *two*-sided identity, meaning $e\star x = x \star e = x$.  Without loss of generality we can take $e$ to be the first element by rows and columns.  How should the first row and the first column be related?

As far as associativity goes, I'm not sure there's a particularly good way of describing this in terms of the group multiplication table.  It just has to work.  (If you can think of a good way, please let me know!)

Comment: About testing associativity, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511682/how-can-we-determine-associativity-of-a-binary-structure-from-its-cayley-table.